# CoreData not saving Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

for the life of me I cannot figure out why I'm not getting anything saved to CoreData.  I added CoreData.framework in the build phases but still nothing when I look at the Model.sqlite.

AppDelegate

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
        (storeDescription, error) in

        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

then in my MainViewController

```
var timer : Timer?
var distance = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
var run: Run! //name of the entity
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

//...

```
private func saveRun() {
    print("saveRun")
    let newRun = Run(context: context)
    print("got past core data")
    newRun.distance = distance.value
    newRun.duration = Int16(seconds)
    newRun.timestamp = Date()

    for locations in locationList {
        let locationObject = Location(context: context)
        locationObject.timestamp = locations.timestamp
        locationObject.latitude = locations.coordinate.latitude
        locationObject.longitude = locations.coordinate.longitude
        newRun.addToLocations(locationObject)

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        run = newRun
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call `context.save()` and then works

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as I'm really new at this but isnt that whats happening with        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

Comment: There is no error? just the data is not being saved?

Comment: nope. no error in the console.  when I try to use the data to map the points out I get a "no data" error.  when I looked at the sqlite file there's nothing there

Comment: So... I'm a complete idiot.  Its working with the code I posted.  The screwup was with an error in my making code and not knowing how to use Liya properly.  Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: @Rob.R Are you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I'm a complete idiot. Its working with the code I posted. The screwup was with an error in my making code and not knowing how to use Liya properly. Thanks for everyones help

@Francesco Deliro

Good to know.  I'll keep that in mind

Thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0):

Core Data expects to be run on a single thread. Even though that thread doesn’t have to be the main thread, Core Data was not designed to be accessed from different threads.